# PDO query filter based on other row

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is my code:

```
//Connects to Database
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    try
    {
        $dbh = new PDO('dbconnection');
        foreach ($dbh->query('SELECT * from table' ) as $row)
        {
            $instructor = ($_POST["name"]);
            //Loads Certificate Template
            $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('cert.jpg');
            $color = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 82, 122, 124);
            //Sets Font
            $font_path = 'name.ttf';
            //Calls first name from database
            $firstname = $row['fname'];
            //Makes entire first name lower case
            $firstnamelower = strtolower($firstname);
            $firstnameucfirst = ucfirst($firstnamelower);
            //Calls Last Name From Database
            $lastname = $row['lname'];
            $lastnamelower = strtolower($lastname);
            $lastnameucfirst = ucfirst($lastnamelower);
            $name = $firstnameucfirst . ' ' . $lastnameucfirst;
            $font_size = 75;
            imagettftext($jpg_image, $font_size, 0, 810, 530, $color, $font_path, $name);
            imagettftext($jpg_image, 40, 0, 375, 945, $color, $font_path, $instructor);
            imagejpeg($jpg_image, 'images/' . $name . '.jpg', 50);
            imagedestroy($jpg_image);
        }
        $dbh = null;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }
    echo "All certificates have been created."

    ?>
```

So I'm trying change it so only images that meet another requirement are processed. Basically I need to use WHERE column_name operator value; but when I do I get errors, I've googled it and I don't really understand what they are saying. Is there another bit of code that is needed to accomplish this using pdo?

This is the error I'm getting Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: You didn't set PDO to throw exceptions, so it would only throw one on connect failure. On query failure, it errors silently by default, and that's probably what you're seeing here.  Turn on `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` after establishing your connection http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php  You'll get a full idea of what has gone wrong.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I did that and nothing changed, still throws the same error

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from that fact that your $pdo->query returns false on failure instead of an empty array.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

foreach expects an array.

Adjust your code:

```
$dbh = new PDO('dbconnection');

// Throw exceptions on errors
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// To make it easier to debug
$sql = 'SELECT * from table';

// To allow check for failuer
$rows = $dbh->execute($sql);

if ($rows === false) ... oopsie

foreach($rows as $row) ...
```

Then get your query to work.  Consider using mysql directly to check your sql.